# Jquery AJAX not loading page, despite page existing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm relatively new to the whole AJAX thing and I'm currently editing a script that will open a modal box, and then load the requested content into said box. I have the following Javascript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$('a[name=modal]').click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var maskHeight = $(document).height();
    var maskWidth = $(window).width();

    //Set height and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
    $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});  
    $('#mask').fadeTo(600,0.75); 

    var load_page = $(this).attr('ajax');

    //Get the window height and width
    var winH = $(window).height();
    var winW = $(window).width();

    // Set the loading HTML to be displayed
    var loadingHTML = '<center><img src="_img/progress_bar.gif"/></center>';

        //Set the loading bar
        $('#placeholder').html(loadingHTML).fadeTo(600,1);
        $('#placeholder').css('top',  winH/2-$('#placeholder').height()/2);
        $('#placeholder').css('left', winW/2-$('#placeholder').width()/2);

    // Ajax load
    $('#ajax').load('_content/' + load_page + '.php', null, function(){  
        $('#ajax').css('top',  winH/2-$('#ajax').height()/2);
        $('#ajax').css('left', winW/2-$('#ajax').width()/2);
        $('#ajax').fadeTo(600,1);
    });   

});

$('.window .close').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#mask, #box, #ajax').hide();
});    

//if mask is clicked
$('#mask').click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $('#ajax, #placeholder').hide();
});
```

});

And also the following HTML,

```
<div id="mask"></div>
<div id="placeholder"></div>
<div id="ajax"></div>
```

My CSS is also,

```
    #mask 
{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 9000;
  background: url("../_img/mask.png") repeat;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#placeholder
{
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9050;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#ajax
{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9100;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
}
```

The script displays the loading bar but then doesn't display the Modal box with the AJAX content, the page does exist on my Localhost. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try changing     /_content/ instead of _content/ only

Comment: Does the modal dialog show up if you embed the content of that page literally in the .load() call?

Comment: var load_page = $(this).attr('ajax'); this does not make sense, why u need this invalid?

Comment: @JapanPro I'm using the A tags, <a href="#!/beta" name="modal" ajax="beta"> and then it would goto "_content/beta.php" to load the page dynamically.

Comment: Also @JosephWeissman it's displaying text when I use $('#ajax').html('Lorem ipsum.').fadeTo(600,1);

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because the site cannot find _content folder as it may not be in the same directory as the javascript file. Try ../_content and if that doesnt work, just try using the entire url: http://example.com/a/b/_content/...